# add_action does not work when instance multiple tab-containers via template-file

Tags: customization, actions, oop

I wrote my first class in functions.php which I want to use to create multiple tabs with a simple call all over my template files. When I create a new instance directly in  functions.php everything is fine for that instance. But when I call my class via a helper function outside my functions.php, all action hooks do not take effect. Are there any suggestions how to get this done?

Regards

```
class EasyTabs {

private static $instance;

public static function get_instance() {

    if ( !self::$instance instanceof self )
        self::$instance = new self;
    return self::$instance;

}

public function container_id() {
    $id = rand(1000,9999);
    return $id;
}

public function get_the_tabs() {
    ...
}

public function tabs_js() {
    ...
}

public function tabs_styles_and_scripts() {
    // style
    wp_register_style('jquery-easytabs-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/easytabs/style.css', array(), '', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-easytabs-style');

    //script
    wp_register_script('jquery-easytabs-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/easytabs/jquery.easytabs.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easytabs-min');
    wp_register_script('jquery-hashchange-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/easytabs/jquery.hashchange.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-hashchange-min');
}

public function __construct() {
    //actions
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array ( $this, 'tabs_styles_and_scripts' ));
    add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'tabs_js'));
}

}

if ( !function_exists( 'the_tabs' ) ) {
    function the_tabs() {
        echo EasyTabs::get_instance()->get_the_tabs();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for the hint, looking for a hook which fires later did the trick: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wp_enqueue_script-after-wp_head

```
class RFRQ_Tabs {

    public $containerID;
    public $posttype;

    public function __construct( $posttype ) {
        // set vars
        $this->set_container_ID();
        $this->set_posttype($posttype);
        //add scripts and styles
        add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'scripts'));
        add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', array($this, 'ex_scripts'), 1);
    }

    ...

    public function scripts() {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
            echo "jQuery(document).ready( function() {";
                echo "jQuery('#tab-container-" . $this->get_container_ID() . "').easytabs();";
            echo "});";
        echo "</script>";
    }


    public function ex_scripts() {        
        if (is_admin())
            return;
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-easytabs-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/easytabs/jquery.easytabs.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-easytabs-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/easytabs/style.css', array(), '', 'all');
        }  
}
/**
 * RFRQ
 * helper function to instance an tab-object
 */
if (!function_exists('the_tabs')) {
    function the_tabs( $posttype ) {
        $easytabs = new RFRQ_Tabs( $posttype );
        echo $easytabs->get_the_tabs();
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you calling `the_tabs` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you call `the_tabs` function (so add your actions to hooks) too late (after these hooks were fired).

For example if you call it in some template file (i.e. single.php) after `wp_head` function call, your filters won't run - you add them to this hook after it already was fired.